# Using waypoints plugin to display elements one by one

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-waypoints

I'm trying to display 3 elements (test 1, test 2, test 3) one after each other once these elements become visible in the web browser / viewport. I'm using the code below that I found on the internet.
Fadein works but it starts immediately when the page is loaded instead of being triggered by user scroll down when it reaches the "waypoint". Maybe this is due to the offset code that I don't understand? What does it do in this case?
Many thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.test1').waypoint(function(event, direction) {
    $(this).fadeIn(1500);
}, {
    offset: function() {
       return -$(this).height();
    }
});

$('.test2').waypoint(function(event, direction) {
    $(this).fadeIn(2000);
}, {
    offset: function() {
       return -$(this).height();
    }
});

$('.test3').waypoint(function(event, direction) {
    $(this).fadeIn(2500);
}, {
    offset: function() {
       return -$(this).height();
    }
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Elements with `display:none` do not live in the same place on the document as they do when they are visible. This is kind of the point of `display:none`. Scripts trying to read the position of these elements like Waypoints are usually handed back a `0` as if they were positioned at the top of the page, hence why they fire immediately.

The best way to address this is to stop using `display:none` + `fadeIn` and switch to animating opacity. Example below.

Also, aside, Waypoints version 2.0+ got rid of the event parameter, so I've removed it here as well. I've also changed your offset. `-$(this).height()` would trigger the fadeIn when the element completely leaves the top of the viewport.

```
$('.test1, .test2, .test3').css('opacity', 0);

$('.test1').waypoint(function(direction) {
  $(this).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 1500);
}, {
  offset: 'bottom-in-view'
});

// etc
```